# Style with ruler and entity count in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, feature-count

My layer style is rule based.

[image]

The number of entities is displayed.

[image]

When I uncheck certain items in the variable, the number of entities not displayed ends up going to zero.

[image]

[image]

Redisplaying the items in question does not update the display of the number of items. Only loading the layer style allows you to return to normal.
Is this a bug? (I can't understand what action triggers this reset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a weird behavior but not a bug. I think you just used it in a way that ended up looking like it is a bug.

- Changing the visibility of a category in the legend **never** triggers a recount of features.
- Changing the visibility of a category in the symbology properties and applying **always** triggers a recount upon applying the changes.

[image]

So if you mix both operations the behavior might look weird but it isn't really.

Comment: Coterreau THANKS. A modification of the layer acts the same.
I uncheck certain items, I modify my layer (by adding an attribute for example or a point), I register them and the number of items is recalculated by counting the unchecked items.